# To access sibilings div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to alert panel-heading text when I click panel-footer

thanks in advance i tried .val() also but not working

```js
$('.panel .panel-footer').on('click',function (e) {
  alert($(this).parent('.panel').closest('.panel-heading .panel-title').text());
            });
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Super Admin</h3>
            <div class="right">
           on type="button" class="btn-toggle-collapse"><i class="lnr lnr-question-circle"></i></button>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
                <div>0 Members</div>
     </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
         <div>View All<i class="lnr lnr-arrow-right pull-right"></i></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I typically use `$(this).closest('.panel').find('.panel-heading')`

Answer (score 1):

Update `closest` to `find`, closest goes up and not down

```
$('.panel .panel-footer').on('click',function (e) {
    alert( $(this).parent('.panel').find('.panel-title').text() );
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/closest/ it traverses up the DOM tree

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

but you want to traverse down since you are already at the parent level(`$(this).parent('.panel')`).

So we use `find()` https://api.jquery.com/find/ which traverses down

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Answer (score 0):

Replace [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) by [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```js
$('.panel .panel-footer').on('click',function (e) {
  alert($(this).parent('.panel').find('.panel-heading .panel-title').text());
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Super Admin</h3>
            <div class="right">
           <button type="button" class="btn-toggle-collapse"><i class="lnr lnr-question-circle"></i></button>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
                <div>0 Members</div>
     </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
         <div>View All<i class="lnr lnr-arrow-right pull-right"></i></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the 'siblings' approach, that will work, as you're triggering off the panel-footer el.

```js
$('.panel .panel-footer').on('click',function (e) {
  console.log($(this).siblings(".panel-heading").text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Super Admin</h3>
            <div class="right">
           <button type="button" class="btn-toggle-collapse"><i class="lnr lnr-question-circle"></i></button>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
                <div>0 Members</div>
     </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
         <div>View All<i class="lnr lnr-arrow-right pull-right"></i></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```